# I installed firewall-configuration and lost the wifi

Tags: wireless, internet, firewall, connection

to keep the PC safe, I installed firewall-configuration from Ubuntu software:

[image]

As soon as the installation was over, I lost the WiFi connection (and even Rstudio cannot connect with R, by the way). I removed it with `sudo apt-get remove firewall-config` but the WiFi is still dead.

How can I reestablish the wifi? and do I need a firewall in ubuntu? and an antivirus? (if yes, is clamAV OK?)

Thanks

Comment: Details in the picture.To note that this firewall resulted not installed in the Ubuntu Software window...

Comment: sorry, the command was for `firewall-config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have removed the `firewall-config` software, but the firewall rules may still be applying to your connections. Try to clear them with these commands:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F
```

Then maybe reboot to make sure they've been cleared.

Another thing you can try is to disable the Uncomplicated Firewall `ufw` used by Ubuntu:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

If you want to use a firewall in Ubuntu, I recommend you read about how to use `ufw`.

Comment: And no, you should not need to use the firewall in Ubuntu unless you're exposing your computer directly to the Internet (since you're using Wi-Fi, your Wi-Fi router firewall should be enough for you). You should not need any kind of antivirus either.

Comment: thank you! it worked even without rebooting.

Comment: One more thing: on start up, the connection was again lost and I had to run these commands again. Is there a way to make them permanent? Why this issue if firewall-config has been removed? Thanks

Comment: There may be something restoring the rules on each boot. Try to do `nano /etc/rc.local` and in the text file that opens see if there is a line referring to iptables. In that case post back here to check how to solve this permanently.

Comment: This file is empty, actually I don't think it exists...